# Can anyone help me in fixing the issue (terminating the instance due to error 474) and then Instance terminated by PMON

Tags: oracle

I get these kinds of errors in my oracle logs many times leading to the abnormal shutdown of the oracle instance.

The alert log file contains the logs mentioned below:

```
Fri Feb 28 22:05:09 2020
Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
Fri Feb 28 22:05:12 2020
System state dump requested by (instance=1, osid=26083 (PMON)), summary=[abnormal instance termination].
Fri Feb 28 22:05:12 2020
PMON (ospid: 26083): terminating the instance due to error 474
System State dumped to trace file /ora01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace/orcl_diag_26097.trc
Fri Feb 28 22:05:14 2020
ORA-1092 : opitsk aborting process
Fri Feb 28 22:05:14 2020
ORA-1092 : opitsk aborting process
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20200228220512], requested by (instance=1, osid=26083 (PMON)), summary=[abnormal instance termination].
Instance terminated by PMON, pid = 26083
Sat Feb 29 08:40:40 2020
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
```

Comment: You have an internal error as pointed out  in the answer. You will have to contact Oracle for support or create a login on Oracle Support site. Then you can access the required **Doc ID  1361872.1**.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your trc file to confirm, but it sounds an awful lot like this

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1361872_1.html

```
Instance Terminated With Error ORA-00474: SMON Process Terminated With Error (Doc ID 1361872.1)
Last updated on JULY 23, 2019
```

If you login to the MOS system, you'll see the the cause is due to a corrupted INDEX. A diagnostic and remediation script is provided to verify and fix the problem.

Any time you get a message like this or a ORA-600 message, the first place to go is My Oracle Support.

Comment: Hi thatjeffsmith, I got the error again and I don't have access to oracle support so can you please help. You can look for the files regarding the files with the help of the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xRjJetqh0wDQh2W1N37mrdx87FBASGIQ

Comment: you need to pay for oracle support, and then use oracle support

Comment: Agreed.  Trying to run Oracle Database /without/ an Oracle support contract is like skydiving without a parachute.  Everything's just fine ... until, very suddenly, it isn't!